# POST request for logging in a user in Mochajs

Tags: mocha.js, passport.js, bcrypt

I'm trying to write a Mocha test for logging a user in to an app.

The login page is located at `http://localhost:3000/login`.  I have this so far:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const assert = require('assert')
const app = require('../server')    

before(function(done) {
  // This creates a connection to my local db
  mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/my_match_local_dev', done);
})

describe('log a user in', function() {

  it('logs the user in', function(done) {
    request(app)
    .post('/login')
    .send({ username: 'user_farid', password: 'asdfasdf'})
    .then(function(res) {
      console.log('res.request._data\n', res.request._data)
    })
  })
})
```

The test is passing, which is a problem because the password is actually `asdf`.

In my actual app, I'm using `passport` for user authentication, and `bcryptjs` to encrypt the password in the database.

How do I write a test for this?

Comment: mocha is quite simple: if your test function throws an error - the test fails, if it does not throw an error - the test succeeds. If an assertion is not met - you throw an error (assertion libraries like chai or your supertest do that for you). You do not use the `.expect` functions, nor do you throw an error when the result does not look like you expected. So there is no way for mocha to know that your test failed.

Comment: I appreciate your reply, but I'm not 100% sure it answered my question.

Comment: it is a comment for a reason^^. But the question still remains: what is your server supposed to answer when confronted with a wrong password and where is your assertion that checks the response? I see that you require `assert` but you don't seem to use it. Neither do you use `supertest`s `expect` function. So I am not sure what the aim of your test is. In your test description you write that it shall log in, but in your question you say that you use the wrong password purposefully. This does not match. What do you want to test?

Comment: It seems that this would require doing a fake server? Have you something like `sinon.js`?